# How to detect circle defects?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Is there any way to tell if a circle has such defects? Roundness does not work. Or is there a way to eliminate them?

[image]

```py
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnts[0],True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnts[0])
    roundness = 4*pi*area/(perimeter*perimeter)
    print("Roundness:", roundness)
```

Comment: Try minEnclosing circle and compare the area to a HoughCircle result or a RANSAC circle detection. Will only work for convex defects.

Comment: Or use distanceTransform and for every circle-point of a detected circle (or minEnclosingCircle) read the distance value and choose a proper threshold.

Comment: Use HoughCircle to find the circle (center and radius). Then remove the circle by making it black inside or subtracting it. Then count non-zero pixels in the remaining image to see how many pixels are still white, which are the defects you show. If a small number, then probably just edge roughness and not a defect. If a large number, then you have a defect as you show.

Comment: Ebbi, it is very rude to delete the question after you got an answer. People write answers here not just for you, but for future visitors. I wouldn’t have put in the effort of writing all of that if it were just for you. By deleting the post, you hid my effort from the future visitors that hopefully will benefit from it. Instead, accept the answer if it was useful to you, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5):

The "roundness" measure is sensitive to a precise estimate of the perimeter.  What `cv2.arcLength()` does is add the lengths of each of the polygon edges, [which severely overestimates the length of outlines](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/310/). I think this is the main reason that this measure hasn't worked for you. With a better perimeter estimator you would get useful results.

An alternative measure that might be more useful is "circularity", defined as the coefficient of variation of the radius. In short, you compute the distance of each polygon vertex (i.e. outline point) to the centroid, then determine the coefficient of variation of these distances (== std / mean).

I wrote a quick Python script to compute this starting from an OpenCV contour:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read in OP's example image, making sure we ignore the red arrow
img = cv2.imread('jGssp.png')[:, :, 1]
_, img = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, 0)

# get the contour of the shape
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contour = contours[0][:, 0, :]

# add the first point as the last, to close it
contour = np.concatenate((contour, contour[0, None, :]))

# compute centroid
def cross_product(v1, v2):
    """2D cross product."""
    return v1[0] * v2[1] - v1[1] * v2[0]

sum = 0.0
xsum = 0.0
ysum = 0.0
for ii in range(1, contour.shape[0]):
    v = cross_product(contour[ii - 1, :], contour[ii, :])
    sum += v
    xsum += (contour[ii - 1, 0] + contour[ii, 0]) * v
    ysum += (contour[ii - 1, 1] + contour[ii, 1]) * v

centroid = np.array([ xsum, ysum ]) / (3 * sum)

# Compute coefficient of variation of distances to centroid (==circularity)
d = np.sqrt(np.sum((contour - centroid) ** 2, axis=1))
circularity = np.std(d) / np.mean(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

This make me think of a similar problem that I had. You could compute the **signature** of the shape. The signature can be defined as, for each pixel of the border of the shape, the distance between this pixel and the center of the shape.

For a perfect circle, the distance from the border to the center should be constant (in an ideal continuous world). When defects are visible on the edge of the circle (either dents or excesses), the ideal constant line changes to a wiggly curve, with huge variation when on the defects.

It's fairly easy to detect those variation with FFT for example, which allows to quantify the defect significance.

You can expand this solution to any given shape. If your ideal shape is a square, you can compute the signature, which will give you some kind of sinusoidal curve. Defects will appear in a same way on the curve, and would be detectable with the same logic as with a circle.

[image]

I can't give you an code example, as the project was for a company project, but the idea is still here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Threshold on white (to remove the red arrow)
- Apply Hough Circle
- Draw the circle on the thresholded image for comparison
- Draw a white filled circle on black background from the circle parameters.
- Get the difference between the thresholded image and the drawn circle image
- Apply morphology open to remove the ring from the irregular boundary of the original circle
- Count the number of white pixels in the previous image as the amount off defect

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('circle_defect.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# threshold on white to remove red arrow
lower = (255,255,255)
upper = (255,255,255)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# get Hough circles
min_dist = int(ww/5)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(thresh, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=min_dist, param1=150, param2=15, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
print(circles)

# draw circles on input thresh (without red arrow)
circle_img = thresh.copy()
circle_img = cv2.merge([circle_img,circle_img,circle_img])
for circle in circles[0]:
    # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
    # corresponding to the center of the circle
    (x,y,r) = circle
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    r = int(r)
    cv2.circle(circle_img, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 255), 1)

# draw filled circle on black background
circle_filled = np.zeros_like(thresh)
cv2.circle(circle_filled, (x,y), r, 255, -1)

# get difference between the thresh image and the circle_filled image
diff = cv2.absdiff(thresh, circle_filled)

# apply morphology to remove ring
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
result = cv2.morphologyEx(diff, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# count non-zero pixels
defect_count = np.count_nonzero(result)
print("defect count:", defect_count)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('circle_defect_thresh.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('circle_defect_circle.jpg', circle_img)
cv2.imwrite('circle_defect_circle_diff.jpg', diff)
cv2.imwrite('circle_defect_detected.png', result)

# show images
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('circle_filled', circle_filled)
cv2.imshow('diff', diff)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Input without Red Arrow:

[image]

Red Circle Drawn on Input:

[image]

Circle from HoughCircle:

[image]

Difference:

[image]

Difference Cleaned Up:

[image]

Textual Result:

```
defect count: 500
```