# Circularity Calculation with Perimeter & Area of a Simple Circle

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

**Circularity** signifies the comparability of the shape to a circle.
A measure of **circularity** is the shape area to the circle area ratio having an identical perimeter (we denote it as Circle Area) as represented in equation below.

Sample Circularity = Sample Area / Circle Area

Let the perimeter of shape be P, so

P = 2 * pi * r

then

P^2 = 4 * pi^2 r^2 = 4 * pi  * (pi * r^2) = 4 * pi * Circle Area. Thus

Circle Area = Sample Perimeter^2 / (4 * pi)

which implies

Sample Circularity = (4 * pi * Sample Area) / (Sample Perimeter^2)

So with help of math, there is no need to find an algorithm to calculate fit circle or draw it on a right way over shape or etc.

This statistic equals 1 for a circular object and less than 1 for an object that departs from circularity, except that it is relatively insensitive to irregular boundaries.

ok, that's fine, but ... .

In python i try calculate circularity for a simple circle but always i got 1.11. My python approach is:

```
import cv2
import math

Gray_image = cv2.imread(Input_Path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cnt , her = cv2.findContours(Gray_image, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
Perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt[0], True)
Area = cv2.contourArea(cnt[0])

Circularity = math.pow(Perimeter, 2) / (4 * math.pi * Area)
print(round(Circularity , 2))
```

If i use

```
Perimeter = len(cnt[0])
```

then answer is 0.81 which is incorrect again. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

To draw a circle, use following command:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

Fill_Circle = np.zeros((1000, 1000, 3))
cv2.circle(Fill_Circle, (500, 500), 450, (255, 255, 255), -1)

cv2.imwrite(Path_to_Save, Fill_Circle)
```

Comment: You can assume folk on StackOverflow who are likely to answer your question know how to calculate circularity and how to draw a circle, so the first half and last quarter of your question aren't really necessary. So that leaves us with a piece of code which processes an image we can't see and no debugging or indication of what contours it has found...

Comment: I have also tried to detect circles morphologically with a different algorithm and similar to yours. You may check the steps here in my [github repo](https://github.com/yunus-temurlenk/Opencv-Circle-Detection-Without-Houghcircle)

Comment: Dear @MarkSetchell , thank you for your recommendations, but in the shape analysis, roundness and the circularity of a shape sometimes taken as one and even discussed and analyzed with some other indicators or different formulations. The measurement of my index that involved with needed to be clarified because maybe the problem is from somewhere else and I am not paying attention. On the other hand, my major is mathematics and we usually don't say a part of whole things when we ask a question.

Comment: @CrisLuengo , you gave a good suggestion, I did it before, but I have a very similar environment, there are other indicators that work with perimeter.

Comment: @CrisLuengo explain it here https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/310/ .
Thank you very much for your time. Many questions were solved for me. Only inside this library (DIPlib) that you wrote, does it return the perimeter with Corner Count method? (the one that its estimate of perimeter is rotation invariant by the way.)

Comment: @CrisLuengo please leave these comments as an answer for me to choose it. thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74524509/7328782) to a related question, OpenCV's perimeter estimate is not good enough to compute the circularity feature. OpenCV computes the perimeter by adding up all the distances between vertices of the polygon built from the edge pixels of the image. This length is typically larger than the actual perimeter of the actual object imaged. [This blog post of mine](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/310/) describes the problem well, and provides a better way to estimate the perimeter of an object from a binary image.

This better method is implemented (among other places) in DIPlib, in the function [dip.MeasurementTool.Measure()](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/dip-MeasurementTool.html#dip-MeasurementTool-Measure-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-StringArray--dip-UnsignedArray-CL-dip-uint--C), as the feature ["Perimeter"](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/features.html#size_features_Perimeter). [Disclosure: I'm an author of DIPlib].

The feature ["Roundness"](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/features.html#shape_features_Roundness) implements what you refer to as circularity here (these feature names are used interchangeably in the literature). There is a different feature referred to as "Circularity" in DIPlib, which does not depend on the perimeter and typically is more precise if the shape is close to a circle.

This is how you would use that function:

```py
import diplib as dip
import cv2
import numpy as np

Fill_Circle = np.zeros((1000, 1000, 3))
cv2.circle(Fill_Circle, (500, 500), 450, (255, 255, 255), -1)

labels = dip.Label(Fill_Circle[:, :, 0] > 0)
msr = dip.MeasurementTool.Measure(labels, features=["Perimeter", "Size", "Roundness", "Circularity"])
print(msr)

Circularity = msr[1]["Roundness"][0]
```

For your circle, I see:

- area = 636121.0
- perimeter = 2829.27
- roundness = 0.9986187 (this is what you refer to as circularity)
- circularity = 0.0005368701 (closer to 0 means more like a circle)